# Playing FIFA 14 multiplayer with two keyboards

Tags: controllers, keyboard, windows, windows-8, fifa-14

I am trying to setup a multiplayer environment for FIFA 14 using two keyboards. To do so I've installed VJoy Virtual Joystick from [here](http://www.headsoft.com.au/index.php?category=vjoy). I've been able to configure it with my laptop but the problem is it doesn't work on FIFA 14. I am attaching some screenshots for more details.

[image: USB Game controllers in windows]

*USB Game controllers in windows*

[image: Screenshot showing that windows is able to detect the joystick]

*Screenshot showing that windows is able to detect the joystick*

FIFA14 is able to detect the two extra controllers but when I play with them it doesn't work.

**PS**: I am running windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, But it is not possible to play with 2 keyboards.
It always consider both keyboard as same. I tried all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play fifa 14 or any new fifa by using 2 keyboards by using a software called keyboardsplitter even 2 keyboards can use same keys in this software as it emulates keyboard as an xbox 360 controller. just go to youtube and search djnights keyboard splitter